# What does it mean to create an API on the web?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, api

I have a site built in ASP.NET MVC and uses heavy jQuery client interaction to build a live chat room. Many users parsed the javascript and found the URLs it posted to in order to interact with the chat. They started building bots for fun to play games within the chat channels.

These users keep asking for an "API" to make it easier for them to code against. I thought I knew what an API was but I think I'm still a little fuzzy. Isn't an API any interface that a third party could interact with?

What would it mean to build a web API for my site? Would it just be a document with a list of URLs and how to interact with them?

I have also heard of web services and web references. What are they? What does it mean to build a web service? Does that have anything to do with APIs on the web?

Comment: An API is usually a documented way for developers to interact with an application.  It usually provides features to send and get data by usually using get requests via a URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An API is, literally, an "Application Programming Interface". It is, at its most basic level, *any* interface designed for other software to interact or communicate with it. In a sense, your open URLs are APIs. Of course, entry points intended as user interfaces often aren't very well-factored for writing other software against, so while they're APIs, they probably aren't very *good* APIs, and you will probably find yourself with performance problems on your hands soon.

Web APIs are entry points on an application running on a web server that permit other tools to interact with that web service in some way. Think of it as a "user interface" for software. Your software needs proper security and access controls, however. Consider rate limiting, or you risk a very aggressive bot flooding your server. But that rate limiting needs to be in the user interface for humans, too- or someone will simply write scripts against it.

A web service is any application, running on an Internet-facing server, that can be interacted with via the Internet, generally with an API that allows other web-based utilities to use your service as part of its functionality.

A list of URLs and how to interact with them is all *any* web API is, in the end. Modern-day web API design almost always involves authentication and security tokens (you should probably study the OAuth authentication model used by, among others, Twitter), and there are a variety of competing standards for how to send data, of which JSON is one of the more popular options. Documenting your interface does turn it into an API, but you might want to spend some time deciding if that's really the "right" way for software to interact with your web service- once you've published an API, changing it will break anything that depends on your service!

Comment: It sounds like I'm very much on the right track. This was a very informative answer. I actually already employ authentication, spam prevention, and I even return well-formed JSON. I will probably spruce up some things and document it well, then publish the information to them. Good stuff, thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome, it sounds like you already have most of the hard problems solved! You're dead right, documentation is all you need, and if you've solved all those issues- correctly- without basic training in web API design, you have excellent intuition for it and will likely continue to have great success in designing and implementing web services.

Comment: Well my mentality was to make the data simple so that the server does not enforce or even imply usage of the data, that was up to the client code. I guess I just didn't realize that I was building a decent API in the process. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

An API, or Application Programming Interface, is a set of established protocols for external programs to interact with your application. As you said, the users parsed the javascript and discovered the URL's that you use, and then built programs using those URL's to interact with your app.

Technically, you already have an API, and they have discovered it - that set of URL's that controls opening chat rooms, posting to the rooms, reading others' posts. However, what your users are asking for is a more established, structured set of methods for doing this.

Such methods might include a form of authentication to the application, as well as messages and/or data passed back from the app to the external program allowing the external program to know what happened to its request (versus just HTML coming back, or nothing at all) - like "success", or "error", "unavailable try again", etc.

Comment: Incidentally, see Twitter's API documentation site http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554679/Twitter-API-Documentation for an example of what a comprehensive web app API might look like.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a set of functions that provide an interface to the ASP.NET MVC. Functions like "start chat" or "send message". It would also involve some security tweaks to let other users acess your server.

Comment: So would this just be a list of URLs and what parameters they expect?

Comment: ^^^ yes. exactly so, well-defined URLs that do useful things.

Comment: The answer depends on your back end. Is your communicate done with URLs? Another thing to figure it is how to let others interface with your backend.

Comment: Yeah mine is done all through URLs (action methods in mvc) and the methods return JSON data that the client can use.

Answer (score 1):

They're asking to make the URLs that their bots post to, be very clear and well-defined for what they do.

Often, these "web api's" take structured data in a POST, or CGI variables in a GET, and don't return HTML, but, rather, XML or json or some other programming-friendly return data.

That's the gist of it!

Comment: Awesome. Makes much more sense now. I'm actually already returning JSON from my existing API so that's good to know. Any thoughts on what a web service is?

Answer (score 1):

In its simplest form, you could just do what you suggest in your second to last paragraph and document the API that you're already using (since it sounds like they can already somewhat use your "internal" API).

But if you want to do it "right" you probably need to go back and take a look at the code you've written and find ways to make it more user-friendly to third-parties and also, potentially, to "harden" it against attacks if you're going to be making it easy for people to use.

Comment: Makes sense. Cool. So what is a web service? Is there a difference? Is my chat API also a web service?

Comment: Well, I suppose web service has both a generic context (in which, yes, your API is a web service) and a more specific context (when talking about things like WCF Web Services). In the latter case, Web Services are just one way to do an API via the web.